# How can I show page per category in wordpress? (Yes, category by page!)

Tags: categories, pages

I've added categories and tags to pages, but now I'm trying to add these to a page, but it doesn't show anything unless I add the category to a post...

Could someone take a look at what I'm doing wrong?

```
  // The Query
  query_posts( array ( 'category_name' => 'powershell-start', 'posts_per_page' => -1 ) );

  // The Loop
 while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
    <li>
    <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
  </li>

  <?php endwhile;

  // Reset Query
  wp_reset_query();

  ?>
```

EDIT: I'm sorry I notice im not clear.
I'm trying to show a specific category on a page with the tilte and link to each page. 
But the above part only works when I add the category to a post instead of a page.

This is what I added to my functions.php:

```
/* add categories and tags to pages */
function add_taxonomies_to_pages() {
 register_taxonomy_for_object_type( 'post_tag', 'page' );
 register_taxonomy_for_object_type( 'category', 'page' );
 }
add_action( 'init', 'add_taxonomies_to_pages' );
```

Answer (score -1):

(I can't comment)
How I get it you want to show all posts on specific category on page?

(Question1)

But how you add categories on pages? Using plugin or?

Solution that worked:

[Link](http://spicemailer.com/wordpress/add-categories-tags-pages-wordpres%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8Bs) - He haven't put more hooks and filters to his query

Comment: nop, I added this:

Comment: /* add categories and tags to pages */
function add_taxonomies_to_pages() {
 register_taxonomy_for_object_type( 'post_tag', 'page' );
 register_taxonomy_for_object_type( 'category', 'page' );
 }
add_action( 'init', 'add_taxonomies_to_pages' );

Comment: Have you added pre_get_posts ? There is more info at http://spicemailer.com/wordpress/add-categories-tags-pages-wordpress/